# How to close a statement via resultset?

Tags: java, jdbc

We have lots of legacy code which connects to the database and returns a result set like this AND IS HOLD INSIDE A DEPENDENT JAR LIKE THIS : I can note possibly change it.

On the calling method when I close the resultset, the underlying statement is left open.

Is there any way closing the statement via underlying resultset ?

Comment: Just wondering - aren't you more worried about connections remaining open...? Even if they're from a thread pool, it will eventually run out, won't it?

Comment: you should not pass around connected result sets, use a disconnected rowset and you do not have this problem. Also you *answer* is incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you read my question carefully ? I state that we are returning the resulset. It is legacy code and I just ask if there is a way closing the statement via result set...

Comment: Why are you using `PreparedStatement` if your code is still left susceptible to injection?

Comment: It is inside of a jar that I can not possibly dare to change...

Comment: we read your question and you are not reading the comments for comprehension, you are not doing this the best way possible even with the restrictions you have.

Comment: you realize that using a `PreparedStatement` here is not doing anything since you are dynamically building the statement and it is completely susceptible to sql injection attacks still! If that is all that method is doing, then just **don't use it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You should never pass around connected result sets:

> A CachedRowSet object is special in that it can operate without being
> connected to its data source, that is, it is a disconnected RowSet
> object. It gets its name from the fact that it stores (caches) its
> data in memory so that it can operate on its own data rather than on
> the data stored in a database.
>
> The CachedRowSet interface is the superinterface for all disconnected
> RowSet objects, so everything demonstrated here also applies to
> WebRowSet, JoinRowSet, and FilteredRowSet objects.

Convert the connected resultset to a [disconnected `RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) and close the `Statement/PreparedStatement` and `Connection` before you return the `RowSet`.

[Using CachedRowSets Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html)

#### If you are doing it wrong already this is the correct way to deal with it:

You must call `.close()` in a `finally` block to guarantee that the code is run!

```
public void badFormPassingAroundConnectedResultSets(@Nonnull final ResultSet rs)
{
    try
    {
        while (rs.next()) { /* do something */ }
    }
    catch (final SQLException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // or log.error() but NEVER empty
    }
    finally
    {
        try { rs.getStatement().getConnection().close(); }
        catch (final SQLException e) { LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e); }
    }
}
```

}

#### Note:

Calling `.close()` on a `Connection` object will call `.close()` on all the child objects that have a reference to it as well.

Comment: I do not understand. How does passing the connected resultset to final Nonnull resultset make any difference ?

Comment: Ok just the finally block I need to add then.

Comment: Not that simple! If you think that, you still are not getting it.

Comment: Thanks looks good. QQ: what happens if the connection is already closed when rs.getStatement.getConnection().close() is invoked? A NPE, perhaps?

Comment: Why not read the JavaDoc instead of guessing or speculating what happens?